# Extend timeout for Apache Superset ElasticSearch connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-superset

I'm trying out Apache Superset, and I'm trying to use the Elasticsearch connector to be able to query some indices. It works fine for some basic things, however for larger data sets, when I try to create a chart that take > 10 seconds, it throws an exception.

Is there a config setting that will reach in and increase the timeout for connectors? I can't seem to find anything.

`elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In the connection string, you add query params like `?timeout=100'